# Eclipse 3.6.1 and Tomcat 7 problems

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Well, it is trivial problems... In fact I started using Tomcat 7 (why not) but when I do Run on Server, Eclipse always fails to get the right URL for the servlet, resulting in my trying to find the right combo for minutes. It's so annoying. Do you have any suggestions? Other servers work correctly, like Spring tc server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is that the project doesn't get deployed at all (or do you actually manage to find it in the browser?).

I'm having problems running a project on Tomcat 7 from inside Eclipse, and have so far found no other "solution" than to manually package (using maven) the project and copy the war file into my tomcats webapps dir.

If the problem is really *only* the initial URL being wrong, then please disregard my answer :P

Otherwise, here's another question of similar sort: [Troubleshoot Eclipse's "Run on server" deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180299/troubleshoot-eclipses-run-on-server-deploy/).

EDIT:
I've done some more research, and it turns out that the mojo plugin version 1.1. doesn't work (as well) with tomcat 7, because the deploy path has changed. I'm working on fixing it by adding this line to the `pom.xml` inside the `<plugin> <configuration>` tags:

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
```

But am still having some problems. Will update if I get it working.